# "Grok" defined as "to dig, without hang-up" on which late-60's or early-70's sci-fi drama on PBS?

Tags: story-identification, tv

As a kid in the late 60's or early 70's I remember seeing a fictional drama on PBS of several people who were on a deep space journey.  A young person said something like "I grok that."  When an older man asked what the word meant, the youth said "to dig, without hang-up."  I was a child and I never saw the show again, and never saw or heard it mentioned anywhere else.  I think suspended animation of some type was being used and I seem to recall food pills, but it's been so long I can't be sure.  Just wondering if anyone else remembers that show.

Comment: The word "grok" was coined in Heinlein's *Stranger in a Strange Land*, published in 1961, so the show could be from any time after that.

Comment: And while technically, PBS did not star broadcasting until 1970, it was a direct successor to the previous American public broadcaster NET, which went back to the 1950s.

Comment: I don't know if it's right, so I won't put it as an answer, but it could be the show LOST IN SPACE (1965-1968). It featured a family that included a teen girl and several older men. It also featured a comedically villainous Dr. Smith. It's the right era and has the right characters. I don't know that I would describe it as a drama, so it may not be right.